# Get the title of all the URLs in a list

Tags: windows, software-rec, automation, url

I have a huge list of URLs and I want to get the title of all of them.

Is it possible? (without actually having to visit each and every one of them manually)

I'm using Windows 8

Comment: When you say title do you mean the metadata "title" attribute from the target page's HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... normally i would do this with Linux but here is a little batchfile you can use in Windows: (`sites.txt` would contain your URLs)

`sites.bat`

```
@echo off
if exist titles.txt (del titles.txt)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (sites.txt) do (
  echo Checking %%a
  echo|set /p=%%a ;>> titles.txt
  wget --quiet -O - "%%a" 2> nul | sed -n -e "s!.*<title>\(.*\)</title>.*!\1!p" >> titles.txt
)
type titles.txt
```

Result will be in `titles.txt` (with `URL ;` in front of it for easy importing in a spreadsheet)

You do need `wget` and `sed` for Windows.

You can find them here:

[wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)
[sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

Note: this uses a simple `sed`-command to extract the title. This could go wrong when a `title` tag also exists in the body (or it has no title). If that's the case you can find more complex checks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312154/wget-page-title).